# PHP Has Limited Functionality With MySQL - CentOS

Tags: mysql, apache, centos

**Overview**: This is a bit of a broad questions since I've spent a lot of time trying to debug it and look up help online. I've seen several websites that say to grant permissions to a user through command line to access MySQL, but they don't seem to work.

**Problem**: Apache can connect with the database and insert data into it, but cannot retrieve data from stuff like select.

Is this a configuration issue? I'm driving myself nuts trying to look for an answer. It works on Windows, but not on Linux.

```
75.83.167.113 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:28 -0400] "POST /?base=main                                                                          &page=vote HTTP/1.1" 500 3447 "http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=ma                                                                          in&page=vote" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/                                                                          537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
75.83.167.113 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:28 -0400] "GET /?base=main&                                                                          page=vote HTTP/1.1" 200 4584 "http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=mai                                                                          n&page=vote" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/5                                                                          37.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
66.249.66.138 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:32 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=rankings&job=pirate&start=1260 HTTP/1.1" 200 6024 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (cible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
75.83.167.113 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:54 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=rankings HTTP/1.1" 200 7159 "http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=main&page=vote" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
75.83.167.113 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:54 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=vote HTTP/1.1" 200 4584 "http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=main&page=vote" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
75.83.167.113 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:55 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=vote HTTP/1.1" 200 4584 "http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=main&page=vote" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
75.83.167.113 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:58 -0400] "POST /?base=main&page=vote HTTP/1.1" 500 3447 "http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=main&page=vote" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
75.83.167.113 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:58:58 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=vote HTTP/1.1" 200 4584 "http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=main&page=vote" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
66.249.66.142 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:59:06 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=rankings&job=aran&start=1290 HTTP/1.1" 200 6020 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.66.142 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:59:06 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=rankings&job=magician&start=1245 HTTP/1.1" 200 6028 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.66.138 - - [17/Jun/2016:23:59:29 -0400] "GET /?base=main&page=rankings&job=beginner&start=1260 HTTP/1.1" 200 6028 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

PHP Error

```
[Sat Jun 18 00:02:57 2016] [error] [client 75.83.167.113] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /var/www/html/dynasty/sources/public/vote.php on line 29, referer: http://www.dynastyms.net/?base=main&page=vote
```

Lines in which the error occurs:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, SUM(times) as amount FROM votingrecords WHERE NOT account='' AND NOT account='0' AND account='".$account."' AND siteid = '".$siteid."'"); // or die('Error - Could not look up vote record!');
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Are you sure on saying Apache connects to database? Not php or any other programming language?

Comment: From your shell on the web server, run this command for a live view of your server logs:
`sudo tail -f /var/log/httpd/*`
Then try to view your website.  The logs should give you a hint of the problem.  If you can't solve it, post the relevant log output here.

Comment: @MitchJackson I don't have experience in web stuff so it's hard for me to debug. I posted the log.

Comment: show your code problem is may be there

Comment: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object is your relevant error.  $mysqli is not a correctly instantiated object.  You should work back from there in your code and find the error.

Comment: @MitchJackson I know it's not a problem with the code because it works perfectly fine on my Windows computer, but when I run it on Linux it fails.